# Looking for manga about a boy who goes back in time to prevent tragedies

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga starts off with the mc making a time machine he successfully builds it and goes back in time and meets his childhood friend (who died in the future) he goes into her house and I think they wanted to get married or be together but the father didn't allow it and forbade her from being with him and leaving the house

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not sure, but is it perhaps ***[Erased](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/rz5pjxl/boku-dake-ga-inai-machi)***?

From [Anime-Planet](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/erased):

> Satoru Fujinuma is a reclusive part-timer with no plans for the future. What sets him apart from the other slackers in his town is an involuntary time travel ability that allows him to jump back several seconds in time in order to prevent accidents and even deaths. As incidents around town begin reminding Satoru of a childhood trauma he'd sooner forget, he finally begins to question what caused his ability to surface and whether or not it's powerful enough to change the past.

- Childhood friends / lovers
- Girl dies
- MC goes back in time
- Parents of the girl do not approve them to be close

Machine is missing though...